# Replace multiple characters in a string at once

Tags: python, string

I want to replace all vowels in a string with a space:

```
string = str(input('Enter something to change'))
replacing_words = 'aeiou'

for i in replacing_words:
    s = string.replace('replacing_words', ' ')

print(s)
```

If this is a wrong code, could someone assist with right codes and explanation, why it didn't work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- You are using a literal 'replacing_words' instead of the variable i inside your for-loop.
- You don't replace the original string to modify it again, instead you create a new string, resulting in only the last replacement to be shown

Here would be the correct code.

```
string = input('Enter something to change')
vowels = 'aeiouy'

for i in vowels:
    string = string.replace(i, ' ')

print(string)
```

Also, I think input returns a string 'type'. So calling str will have no effect. Not sure. Also #2: y is a vowel as well (so are åäö and other umlauts and weird characters if you want to be thorough).

Answer (score 15):

You could define a [translation table](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate). Here's a Python2 code:

```
>>> import string
>>> vowels = 'aeiou'
>>> remove_vowels = string.maketrans(vowels, ' ' * len(vowels))
>>> 'test translation'.translate(remove_vowels)
't st tr nsl t  n'
```

It's fast, concise and doesn't need any loop.

For Python3, you'd write:

```
'test translation'.translate({ord(ch):' ' for ch in 'aeiou'}) # Thanks @JonClements.
```

Comment: On Python 3 you could use: `'test translation'.translate({ord(ch):' ' for ch in 'aeiou'})`...

Answer (score 3):

You are using the `replace` method incorrectly. Since you want to replace each of the characters separately, you should pass a single char every time.

Here is a one-liners that does the trick:

```
string = ''.join(' ' if ch in vowels else ch for ch in string)
```

Comment: If `str` isn't previously defined (and it'd be a bad choice of name as it's shadowing a builtin) then this'll error out on the `.replace` call. Also - that list-comp is just wrong... So this either won't run or won't work...

Comment: The map/lambda is a bit overkill but it at least works now - have you considered just `''.join(' ' if ch in vowels else ch for ch in string)` ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
string=raw_input("Enter your something to change")
replacing_words = 'aeiou'
for m in replacing_words:
    string=string.replace(m, ' ')
print string
```

Answer (score 0):

In Python, strings are immutable.

```
# Python 3.6.1

""" Replace vowels in a string with a space """

txt = input('Enter something to change: ')
vowels = 'aeiou'
result = ''

for ch in txt:
    if ch.lower() in vowels:
        result += ' '
    else:
        result += ch

print(result)
```

Testing it:

```
Enter something to change: English language
 ngl sh l ng  g
```

In Python 3.x, you can also write (nothing to import):

```
vowels = 'aeiouAEIOU'
space_for_vowel = str.maketrans(vowels, ' ' * len(vowels))
print('hello wOrld'.lower().translate(space_for_vowel))

h ll  w rld
```

Answer (score 0):

You can first check in string if words are in vowel string then replace:

```
string = str(input('Enter something to change'))

replacing_words = 'aeiou'

for i in string:
    if i in replacing_words:
        string=string.replace(i," ")

print(string)
```

And if you want to keep original copy and also want to change string then:

```
string = str(input('Enter something to change'))
string1=string[:]
replacing_words = 'aeiou'

for i in string1:
    if i in replacing_words:
        string1=string1.replace(i," ")

print("{} is without vowels : {} ".format(string,string1))
```

output:

```
Enter something to change Batman
Batman is without vowels : B tm n
```